# Does my Masters Conversion course count towards the Australian ACS requirements?

Tags: australia, skilled-migration

Edit: they did accept this degree as equivalent to an Australian Masters.

I am considering applying for an Australian skilled immigration Visa as a software engineer.

I have a BA in History and an MSc in Computer Science (specifically http://www.bristol.ac.uk/study/postgraduate/2017/eng/msc-computer-science/, but from 2007-2008), plus 7ish years of experience as a software engineer.

However, I am concerned that my degree might not count towards the requirements (in which case I think I need to fill out an annoying recognition of prior learning form and won't get as many points).

The part which is confusing me is in the [Guidelines for Applications](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20-%20June%202017.pdf). It states:

> A post graduate qualification (Graduate Diploma or Masters) that do not require a Bachelor with an ICT
>   major for entry into the course, must have:
>
> A minimum of 3 semesters or at least 1.5 years of full-time study

My MSc was 180 credit points, where in the UK students normally take 120 credits worth of units a year, but it was only a 12 month course. I have no idea how many semesters you would call it.

So my question is: how do I find out whether my degree is likely to be accepted? Paying $500 Australian and filling out all the forms only to be rejected would be quite annoying. And I presume somewhere the ACS must maintain a list of degrees which they accept for this purpose.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it was 12 months, then it should count as 3 semesters (fall, spring, summer) but I am not a lawyer nor an immigration official.

Comment: Note that all the assessments of the degree if not qualified at a particular level just mean that you have to have your work experience evaluated instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously I can only go by my own experience and I am not an immigration consultant

But

I was in this exact situation - I have a 1 year conversion from Sheffield University MSc Information Systems. ACS assessed it as being an relevant degree with a Major component of ICT. It was the highest level of qualification. As the comment says - because it is 12 months it counts as 3 semesters so you fit in with that description.

All the best - hope it works out for you