# Can I migrate to Australia with bachelor's and master's degrees in different fields?

Tags: australia, skilled-migration

I have a bachelor's degree in agriculture and after that I am going to get a master's degree in IT (computer networking) by summer 2018, without getting a bachelor's degree in IT.

I have more than 5 years work experience in IT (computer networking and computer maintainer supervisor).

Can emigrate to Australia under the skilled migration plan? Is there any hope for me?

Answer (score 1):

There is hope. I successfully applied for permanent residency with

- BSc Microbiology
- PGCE Secondary Science Teaching
- MSc Information
  Systems

I got the 189 visa as an Analyst Programmer. The MSc counted as

> ICT major which is closely related to your nominated occupation

The first 2 qualifications were largely irrelevant though a degree of any sorts did count towards the points.

Best of luck with your application

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Crab Bucket's example, the ACS accepted my 12-month computer science MSc (which I took after studying 3 years of history).

Details: [Does my Masters Conversion course count towards the Australian ACS requirements?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/does-my-masters-conversion-course-count-towards-the-australian-acs-requirements)