# Should I mention Master's degree in the ACS Skills Assessment?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia, skilled-migration, work-permit

Below details are for my Australian Visa (subclass 189/191/491)

I have completed my **Bachelors** in Electronics and telecommunication engineering *(2010-14)* and
**Masters** in Electrical and Electronics engineering *(2016-18)*

Between the 2 degrees I was working as a Software engineer and post my masters I again have joined a Software developer job. My total job/IT experience is now **5+ years**.

I have received my **skills assessment result from ACS** as (total - 4) years experience *i.e.* **only 1 year.**
*My agent told me not to include my masters in the application and so I didn't.*

Could I have opted for another assessment authority or should I have included masters degree as well to have received a better result?

Please suggest!!!

Comment: I think (thus not an answer) that a 2 year research master's can replace some of the 5 year work requirement, but then only the work post-masters may qualify.

Comment: what qualifies as a research master? I have published a thesis and 5 papers (including conference papers). but nowhere in my degree says particularly as research Master.

is that applicable for outside Australian universities as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does my Masters Conversion course count towards the Australian ACS requirements?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/does-my-masters-conversion-course-count-towards-the-australian-acs-requirements)

Comment: @RC0993 It sounds like you did do a research-based Master's degree. I started out working on one but switched to a course-based one (had to pass a comprehensive test and write a paper) because I didn't plan to do a Ph.D and wanted to graduate!

Comment: I don't think your electrical and electronics Master's would have helped if you were being assessed for software experience.

Comment: @jcm One of the member from a immigration related facebook group  suggested I should have gone for Engineers Australia (EA) assessment for Engineering Technologist (ET). That would give me 5 extra points and also lets me work as software engineer in Australia. Is that correct?

Comment: No idea. But it seems unlikely given you don't have EE work experience.